# In Eclipse C/C++ IDE, how do I disable accessibility features to unbind the F10 key from accessing main menus, like in Eclipse Java IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, accessibility, key-bindings

My first ever Stack Overflow question, merged from two text boxes:

I do not need F10 to access the Eclipse IDE main menus. In the Eclipse Java IDE I can bind F10 to whatever action I like. However, in the Eclipse C/C++ IDE I am now using (the Eclipse C/C++ Developers Toolkit (CDT) installation), the F10 key cannot be bound to any action because it always opens the menu system, just as if I had pressed the Alt key. I can even switch back and forth between the Eclipse Java and Eclipse C/C++ IDEs and the F10 key functionality changes with it.

In other words, how can I make the F10 key behave the same way for the C/C++ IDE as it does for the Java IDE, where the Java IDE allows the F10 to be bound to any action?

From this Eclipse.org help page, I know it has to do with "Accessibility features in Eclipse":
https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Faccessmain.htm

Why should this be enabled in the C/C++ IDE but not the Java IDE?

Switching between a Java workspace and a C/C++ workspace changes the ability to bind actions to the F10 key. I want the C/C++ IDE environment to not use the Accessibility features which prevent binding actions to the F10 key. Since this is done in the Eclipse Java IDE, I know it is possible to do in Eclipse.

I have even unbound ALL KEYS from ALL ACTIONS, but F10 still switches focus to the menu system, which is identical behavior to the Alt key in most Windows applications.

In looking up this issue, I have found that the root of the behavior is from "Accessibility features in Eclipse". See this Eclipse.org link:

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Faccessmain.htm

Comment: Are there any commands bound to the F10 shortcut: in the preferences _General > Keys_, please filter for `F10` and tell which commands are listed then?

Comment: Are you sure F10 isn't owned by the windowing system?